# initialize static member with pointer generated inside scope

Tags: c++, scope, static

I have a static member variable in class A which is a pointer to an object of class B:

```
class B{};

class A
{
  static B* b_ptr;
};
```

I want to initialize it with an instance of B which is located inside another object (c):

```
class C
{
  B b; // <--- I want b_ptr to point to this object
} c;
```

I am finding it "impossible" to initialize because b_ptr cannot be initialized in class C or indeed in any sort of scope.

Is it possible, somehow? If so, is it ill-advised?

Comment: why do you find it impossible? what did you try?

Comment: ***is it ill-advised?*** It's ill-advised because it will lead to a dangling pointer if `C` is freed.

Comment: as the answer already mentions, globals are not nice, pointers to globals arent any nicer, and wrapping them as a static member inside a class also doesnt make it better. To know if this is ill-advised we would need to know what is the goal of this construct.

Answer (score 4):

This look OK to me, (by which I mean it should compile).

```
class C
{
public:
  B b;
} c;

B* A::b_ptr = &c.b;
```

But pointers, static members, global variables, they all have their place, but all together seems ill advised to me.